# How to use the fixture 'test_client in pytest-aiohttp

Tags: pytest, aiohttp

there is an elementary test

```
from aiohttp import web

async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello, world')

async def test_hello(test_client, loop):
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', hello)
    client = await test_client(app)
    resp = await client.get('/')
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
    assert 'Hello, world' in text
```

fixture 'test_client' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace, event_loop, event_loop_process_pool, loop, monkeypatch,
> ```
>
> pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, unused_tcp_port, unused_tcp_port_factory

Comment: `test_client` is neither imported nor defined. Where are you expecting it to come from? I'm inclined to think you'd minimally need `import pytest`, if perhaps it's automatically added to the fixture space by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [pytest-aiohttp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-aiohttp) plugin.

```
pip install pytest-aiohttp
```

It is described in very begin of [testing chapter](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/testing.html) in aiohttp documentation.

Comment: after the computer restarts the tests are performed